# Prevent pandas from interpreting 'NA' as NaN in a string : csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How l'm processing a csv file using pandas.
l have to remove blank rows. While trying to do that l noticed that pandas interpret 'NA' as NaN. How can l circumvent that ? 
the steps are : 
1- prevent pandas from interpreting 'NA' as NaN 
2- remove blank rows using `df.dropna()`

Thank you

Comment: if pandas interprets `'NA'` as `NaN` then surely this would make it easier to drop the rows as this is what `dropna` does?

Comment: If you are using `pandas.read_csv` read the docstring, particularly the description of `na_values` and `keep_default_na ` and `na_filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for NaN

```
df[~df.isnull()]
```

for NA

```
df.dropna()
```

Comment: this is incorrect, NA will not be interpreted as `NaN` for `dropna`